# How to use the Scheffe correction

Tags: correlation, multiple-comparisons

I have 4 conditional correlation matrices $C_1, \ldots, C_4$. I want to test each entry in the $k$th matrix, say $\hat{r}_{ij}^{(k)}$, against a reference value $r_{ij}^{0}$ value in a matrix $C_0$.

I do this by checking whether $$-n_{k}\log\left[1 - (\hat{r}_{ij}^{(k)} - r_{ij}^{0})^2\right] > 3.841$$
which is the critical value of a chi-square distribution with 1 degree of freedom at the 0.05 significance level, under the null hypothesis that $\hat{r}_{ij}^{(k)} = r_{ij}^{0}$.

I know I am prone to false positives because of multiple comparisons and I have heard that Scheffe's method can alleviate this problem. This method would also be appropriate since each conditional correlation matrix $C_k$ is estimated based on different sample sizes $n_k$. I understand how this method works in very broad strokes, but I am not sure how I can apply in this particular situation. What are the groups in this case: what contrasts are appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of anova, the Scheffe method is based on testing all possible contrasts, of which there are infinitely many, and using a critical value based on the distribution of the maximum $t$ value among all of them.

But as I understand your question, this is not an anova situation and it'd be tough to figure out that worst-case distribution. Moreover, as I understand it, there are only 4 contrasts you want to test. So applying the Scheffe idea would be quite conservative, even if it is tractable.

In the anova context again, the Bonferroni method is typically less conservative than Scheffe when there are just a handful of tests involved.

I suggest applying a simple Bonferroni correction -- that is, for 4 tests, divide your alpha by 4 so that you use the $100 - 5/4 = 98.75$th percentile of the $\chi^2_1$ distribution for an overall type I error probability of at most 5%. The Bonferroni method is somewhat conservative but is based on a probability inequality that always holds, regardless of the model, sampling distribution, or intercorrelations among the statistics.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I was wondering if it's not a problem to divide alpha by 4, since each matrix has 45 conditional correlations that I compare to their corresponding counterpart in $C_0$?(I admit, these kinds of corrections are not exactly my area of expertise)

Comment: If you want to guard against the possibility of even one type I error among those 180 tests, you may divide alpha by 180. That will, however, be quite conservative. Only you can decide if the stakes are so high that you need that level of protection. Another option is to instead only protect the false discovery rate instead of the overall alpha. You'll need to look that up but there are Bonferroni-based methods for that too.